# Invalid JSON response using asp.net core mvc 3 Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

I've a problem with an exception from DataTable.

In the controller of the API, I'm using [Authorize]. Without this, it works.

By selecting an item start the ajax call...

```
 var urlCompleto = ".....";
 $.ajax({
                'url': urlCompleto,
                'method': "GET",
                'contentType': 'application/json'
}).done(function (data) {
                  ...
            })
            .fail(function () {
                  ....
            })
        });
```

So appare an allert: **DataTables warning: table id=querytable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see** http://datatables.net/tn/1. And the status of the request is 403.

How do I make it work even if authorized?

I tried to put "RequestVerificationToken" in the headers of the ajax call, but nothing...

I tried to AddAntiForgeryToken and pass it like data in the ajax call, but nothing....

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

If I take:

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
```

and pass it like "data" in an ajax call of type:"post" I've no error.
So how can I "pass" this token in an ajax call of type:"get"?